# Do i need to close connection of mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new in mongodb.
And i ma using mongodb 2.6.x. I am trying to connect with mongodb using java driver 2.12.x version and for connecting with mongodb i am using MongoClient. Every time i am doing any operation i am getting message in mongodb admin part like the number of connection is open and every time i am doing some crud operation in mongodb the number of connection increases. So, my concern is should i close the connection or not manually. If i should close the connection manually then what is the process. Because MongoClient from which i am getting the Db object is not giving any method to close the connection.

The code i have written to get the connection is like this:

```
new MongoClient("localhost", 27017).getDB("test");
```

and from here i am getting the DB object. I am trying it with my web application.

if anyone have any idea please let me know should i close the mongodb connection manually. If yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Straight from the documentation `to dispose of an instance, make sure you call MongoClient.close() to clean up resources'. [mongo doc here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/).  Maybe you need to update??

Comment: Thanks but i have mentioned that i am using mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar and i am not getting any method like MongoClent.close(). Can you please let me know in more details if i am wrong. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: Are you trying to call close on the DB or the MongoClient? Method chaining is convenient, but you need to keep a tab on which method returns what refernce.

Comment: My friend as you have mentioned in the first comment like to close the connection like this [MongoClient.close()]. so i am trying like that. I did check the source code of MongoClient and Db file. i didn't get any method like close(). Thanks

Comment: FYI close is not a static method on Mongoclient. close() is a non static member of Mongo.class. So you need to call close() on the instance of mongoclient.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike traditional database drivers, the mongodb java driver [handles the pooling and connection management](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/). So you are safe here. However you may want to add shut-down hooks by calling close on the MongoClient when you shut-down the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have option to make our connection flexible, when we are connection to mongodb using a java driver. I am using a java driver of version 2.13.x. Where i got some solution like this:

MongoClientOptions is a class from which we can get MongoClientOptions.builder() and we do configure the options as per our requirement and finally when we are calling the the MongoClient to get the DB, in the constructor we can pass the  MongoClientOptions for making our connection better and flexible.

the code would be look like this.

```
MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions= MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(500)
 .connectTimeout(1000).socketKeepAlive(false).cursorFinalizerEnabled(true).maxConnectionLifeTime(50)
.writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED).threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(10).readPreference(ReadPreference.primary()).build();


new MongoClient(listOfServer, mongoClientOptions).getDB();
```

I did try this solution and start doing crud operation, where i found that the no of connection i was getting for each hit was simultaneously getting close also.